# polymer change function of on-click button after clicking it

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have an expanding search bar that when I click, expands due to JS that I have written for the on-click function. I also want this on-click function to change so that I can actually search with the search bar when I type something in.

Is this actually possible?

Example...
*click search icon* > search bar expands > *type in question and click search icon* > searches...

**HTML**

```
<paper-input id="searchMe" placeholder="Some text as a placeholder" on-input="inputText">
   <div suffix>
      <paper-icon-button class="clear" id="clearIcon" icon="clear" on-click="clearInput" style="display: none;"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-icon-button class="search" id="searchIcon" icon="search" on-click="searchClick"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
searchClick : function() {
    /* expands the search bar */
    this.$.searchIcon.setAttribut('on-click','doSomethingElse');
}

doSomethingElse : function() {
    /* Does something else */
}
```

### UPDATE 03/07/17

I thought I had sorted this, but I have a bug with it...

I changed the search button when text is input to fire a new function (this will be used to actually search in the future as a PUT or something), however I can't get it to revert back to the original function afterwards... See my GIF for example.

[image]

```
 doSomething : function() { 
     this.$.searchMe.value = 'JS has been switched!';
     this.listen(this.$.iconSearch, 'click','searchClick');
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply toggle an expanded state property of the search bar on click and search or expand based on the current state.

```
searchClick : function() {
    if(this.expanded){
     //do search
    }
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be hiding the button you don't need:

**HTML**

```
<paper-input id="searchMe" placeholder="Some text as a placeholder" on-input="inputText">
  <div suffix>
    <paper-icon-button class="clear" id="clearIcon" icon="clear" on-click="clearInput" style="display: none;"></paper-icon-button>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[expandedBar]]">
      <paper-icon-button class="search" id="searchIcon" icon="search" on-click="searchClick"></paper-icon-button>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!expandedBar]]">
      <paper-icon-button class="search" id="searchIcon" icon="search" on-click="expandBar"></paper-icon-button>
    </template>
  </div>
</paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
expandBar: function() {

  /* expands the search bar */
  ...

  this.set('expandedBar', true);
}

searchClick: function() {
   /* Search */
}
```

Comment: I have only seen Dom-If's once and haven't used them myself yet, but I agree that this could be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this shortly after posting the question, on a GitHub board.
[Here is the solution I found](http://jsbin.com/megenazuha/1/edit?html,output)

Please see the below code to find what worked for me.

```
searchClick : function() {
    /* expands the search bar */
    this.listen(this.$.searchIcon, 'click', 'doSomethingElse'); /* THIS IS THE CORRECT LINE */
}

doSomethingElse : function() {
    /* Does something else */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `on-click` is an attribute and you can change it like any other. Just make sure the first function fires before changing it.

As for what you're trying to accomplish, I can't think of a better way or any reason that would be a bad idea.

Is your code not working? If not I think it's just because there's a typo on `setAttribut`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would fire the event before setting the attribute? I'm pretty new to the deeper functionality of JS. And yes, I spotted my spelling mistake XD

Comment: Now that I think about it, there's actually not a way you could make that happen... the function fires on click and the function is to change the function. I just thought I should quickly point that out in case you accidentally did it and wasted time trying to figure out what was happening.

Comment: It's been bugging me all weekend. I think that I will just change the functionality so that I have different buttons appearing/disappearing. I think that would be simpler.